# Unable to login to Docker from Jenkins environment

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below script, with legacy Jenkins and installation of just docker plugin, I was able to fetch the node image without credentials.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:12.22.1' }
    }
}
```

**Now, it miserably fails with the below error**

```
$ docker login -u user@gmail.com -p ******** https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: docker login failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried setting up environment with Docker credentials like below:

```
pipeline {
        agent {
            docker { image 'node:12.22.1' }
        }
        environment {
            registryCredential: 'dockerhub_id' // created in global credentials
        }
    }
```

Still no luck, the best example to dockerize my login app will be good to unblock myself.

Comment: I think you need `registryCredentialsId` not `registryCredential` see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent

Comment: and it needs to be part of the `docker`  section

Comment: The credentials is part of hub.docker.com. But Jenkins targetting index.docker.io. Should I configure the registry address as well? And for node image, should I store in my docker account or it will find with public container?